# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, apache-spark, build

I write a Spark program with elastic search libraries.

Here is my build.sbt.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark_2.10" % "2.3.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.3.3"
```

Here is error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;
at com.minsu.house.BatchProgram.process(BatchProgram.scala:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

And My code is as follows...

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
val dataframe = sqlContext.sql(sqlString)     // <----- HERE !!!
```

I do not think it has anything to do with the elastic-search library.

It simply seems to be due to dependency or version problems.

What should I do? Help me.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elasticsearch Spark connector version that you are trying to use does not support Spark 2. You have two options here:

- Use Spark 1.6.x since Elasticsearch 2.x does not support Spark 2
- Upgrade the Elasticsearch Spark connector and Elasticsearch itself to 5.x

For instance, I used org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.0 and the following Spark 2 code:

```
// add to your class imports
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

// Use Spark 2.0 SparkSession object to provide your config
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(...).getOrCreate()
// Optional step, imports things like $"column"
import sparkSession.implicits._
// Specify your index and type in ES
val df = spark.esDF("index/type")
// Perform an action
df.count()
```

Comment: Thank you. Anton Okolnychyi!
I will use spark 1.6.x.
So what version of the elastic-search library should I use?

Comment: @minsu sometime ago I used Scala 2.10.6, Spark 1.6.3, and `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.4`

Comment: And I installed elasticsearch with 2.3.3, is it ok to use the library 5.0?

Comment: If you are using Elasticsearch 2.3.3, then the only option is to use Spark 1.6.x. Your artifact will be `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.3.3` (that you tried to use) but Spark version, for instance, 1.6.3.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you.